# Twitter Bootstrap Extend not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am running a rails app and have install the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem (v2.2.8). I am attempting to use the extend method but am having issues:

**home/index.html.erb:**

```
<p class="text-error" >TEST 1</p>
<p class="test" >TEST 2</p>
```

**/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css:**

```
/*
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap

  Use Font Awesome icons (default)
  To use Glyphicons sprites instead of Font Awesome, replace with "require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites"
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome
  */

body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

#error_explanation {
    color: #f00;
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
}
}

.test
{
    @extend .text-error;
}
```

"TEST 1" renders as I would expect, but TEST 2 does not inherit the .text-error formatting.

Comment: That missing trailing semicolon `;` in `@extend .text-error`, is that a typo in this question or is that how it is in your code?

Comment: @vee that is how it was in my code, but I added the semicolon and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @vee is there anything else you see?

Comment: The other and possibly only problem I can spot is the file name, your `@extend` usage tells me that you are using `sass` processor.  That file name needs to be renamed to `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`.  Give that a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filename should be `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` and not `bootstrap_and_overrides.css`.
Now, when our Sass compiles, the `.test` selector becomes `.test, .text-error`